# How to disable Notepad++ comment collapsing

Tags: javascript, notepad++

I'm working on a website and use Notepad++ for coding. I recently came across some sort of comment notation using forward slash and two asterisks `/** */` This is apparently used to collapse everything within the container

```
function foo(){
    //some script
    /***/
    //even more script

    //another line
    }
//text outside function
```

when collapsed it will look like this

```
function foo(){
    //some script
    /***/
//text outside function
```

I have written some comments which Notepad++ interprets as these and it becomes a problem when I try to collapse the function. When I do the rest of the script is collapsed including the ending `</script>` tag

```
  function foo(){
<!--HTML code-->
```

This only works in JavaScript and I haven't found any way to disable it. Notepad++ allows "[user-defined language](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages)" but it only seems to be able to add notations, not change existing.

Is there any way I can disable this?

Comment: What happens if you add another `/***/` somewhere else in the function?

Comment: 1) The SO police are going to get you because this is not a programming question.  
2) I confirm the behavior in Notepad++.  It appears to collapse (fold) to the end of the script.  
3) I've searched in the doc and haven't found this.  
4) Couldn't you just avoid using /***/'s?

Comment: Adding another `/***/` will not make any difference. I try not to use them, but out of curiosity I wanted to know if there was a solution.

As for this not being a programming question; I had a look at other questions tagged Notepad++ before I wrote this and it seemed to be more like the this one. I thought this was an appropriate place, I must’ve been wrong. I will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ gives no options for built-in language lexers. They are in fact part of underlying [**Scintilla** project](http://scitnilla.org).

So, if you are not keen enough to change built-in lexer by yourself, then the answer for you is **there is no way**. Otherwise find your lexer in `scintilla\lexers\` folder in N++ source package and start playing with it. (And if you find solution to effectively solve the problem with `/***/`, you might consider contributing it back to Scintilla project.) Third option is to chcek [Scintilla Bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/bugs/) and if this problem is not reported already, you can create a new bug report.